# C reading and writing with multiple child processes

Tags: c, fork, pipe, dup2

From a parent process in C, I'm running 3 childs, each executing a program.

- Program 1 gets stdin (user input) and prints it to stdout.
- Program 2 gets stdin (should be from program 1), modifies it and
  prints to stdout.
- Program 3 gets stdin (should be from program 2), modifies it and
  prints to stdout

I am getting the output of program3, but the modification of program 2 is not showing.

Below is the relevant code from the parent:

```
if((child1 = fork()) < 0){
    /*fatal*/
}
else if(child1 == 0){ //inside child 1
    dup2(pipe1[1], 1); //child 1 uses pipe1[1] for writing
    close(pipe1[0]);

    execl("program1.out", (char *)0);
}
else{
    if((child2 = fork()) <0){
        /*fatal*/
    }
    else if(child2 == 0){ //inside child 2
        close(pipe1[1]);
        dup2(pipe1[0], 0); //child2 uses pipe1[0] for reading
        dup2(pipe2[1], 1); //child2 uses pipe[1] for writing

        execl("program2.out", (char *)0);
    }
    else{
        if((child3 = fork()) <0){
            /*fatal*/
        }
        else if(child3 == 0){ //inside child 3
            close(pipe2[1]);
            close(pipe1[0]);

            execl("program3.out", (char *)0);
        }
        else{ //inside parent
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }   
}
```

The programs are using fgets and printf for reading/writing.

I have checked previous questions but I couldn't find out what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child3 needs to do:

```
dup2(pipe2[0], 0); // child3 uses pipe2[0] for reading
```

You also need to close all the pipes that a child doesn't use in each child. So child1 needs to:

```
close(pipe2[0]);
close(pipe2[1]);
```

child2 needs to:

```
close(pipe2[0]);
```

and child3 needs to:

```
close(pipe1[0]);
close(pipe1[1]);
close(pipe2[1]);
```

And the parent needs to close ALL the pipes after it forks all the children.

All these closes are needed so that the processes will read `EOF` when the previous program in the pipeline closes the pipe, because a pipe isn't really closed until all processes that have it open close it.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work after adding that. Also have to kill program2.out manually ( cannot open output file program2.out: Text file busy).

Comment: You need to close all the unused pipes in all the child processes.

Comment: Ahhh.. Thank you so much, its working perfectly now :)

Btw, are the child1->pipe2 closes necessary considering it hasnt been duped then?

Comment: Yes. You need to close the pipes if they've been duped or not.